# Integration tests failing to connect localhost

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, github-actions, integration-testing

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Data could not be sent to remote host \"localhost\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/root/.ansible/cp/72dc686b8e\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"localhost\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused\r\ndebug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Cannot assign requested address\r\nssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Cannot assign requested address\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

```bash
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Command exited with status 4 after 0.9616847038269043 seconds.
ERROR: Command "ansible-playbook -i /tmp/ssh-inventory-5veyhtvk.json /root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_data/playbooks/posix_hosts_prepare.yml -e '{"hosts_entries": ["172.17.0.2 nios-simulator # ansible-test 92c84b72-be55-4d0c-8515-cf8d7fa1cd0c"]}' -vvvvvv" returned exit status 4.
```

I have tried checking some of configs but for only stable-2.12, this integration tests failing with the existing host in the Github workflow. I am expecting to resolve this type of issue.

Comment: can you give more context? what do the tests execute? if you run `ssh localhost` in the host where the tests are executed, does it work? (Ansible is being requested to do that)

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your playbook section which tries to execute your command:

- includes `delegate_to: localhost`
- does *not* include `localhost` in `hosts_entries`

---

See "[Delegating tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks)"

> If you want to perform a task on one host with reference to other
> hosts, use the `delegate_to` keyword on a task.
>
> This is ideal for
> managing nodes in a load balanced pool or for controlling outage
> windows.
> You can use delegation with the serial keyword to control the
> number of hosts executing at one time:
>
> ```yaml
> ---
> - hosts: webservers   serial: 5
>
>   tasks:
>     - name: Take out of load balancer pool
>       ansible.builtin.command: /usr/bin/take_out_of_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
>       delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
>
>     - name: Actual steps would go here
>       ansible.builtin.yum:
>         name: acme-web-stack
>         state: latest
>
>     - name: Add back to load balancer pool
>       ansible.builtin.command: /usr/bin/add_back_to_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
>       delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
> ```
>
> The first and third tasks in this play run on 127.0.0.1, which is the machine running Ansible.

---

Other options:

As explained in "[Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions / Local playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks)":

> It may be useful to use a playbook locally on a remote host, rather than by connecting over SSH. This can be useful for assuring the configuration of a system by putting a playbook in a crontab. This may also be used to run a playbook inside an OS installer, such as an Anaconda kickstart.
>
> To run an entire playbook locally, just set the hosts: line to hosts:
> 127.0.0.1 and then run the playbook like so:
>
> ```
> ansible-playbook playbook.yml --connection=local
> ```
>
> Alternatively, a local connection can be used in a single playbook
> play, even if other plays in the playbook use the default remote
> connection type:
>
> ```yaml
> ---
> - hosts: 127.0.0.1   
>   connection: local
> ```